# Images in html tables

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to load image in the html table cell, but its showing a broken image[error: GET http://localhost:4003/jTxK4bqTE.jpeg 404 (Not Found)] even though  the image is loading up in: http://localhost:63342/Tables/public/index.html through my IDE.

The index.html:

```
<div >
  <table bgcolor="#556b2f" class="table table-inverse">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="color: antiquewhite">Flower</th>
        <th style="color: antiquewhite">Fruit</th>
      </tr>
    <td><img ng-src="../jTxK4bqTE.jpeg" width="160" height="113"></td>
        </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: It has nothing to do with the table... why is the port different? Are you sure your server is accessing the right path?

Comment: The port is different because my node server is running in 4003.

Comment: 63342 is  port of the LiveEdit feature in WebStorm.

Comment: can u right click the image that is loading from the IDE and do a view image path or something. I feel the path is being called wrong here..

Comment: Thank  you so much, I right clicked the image, viewed the image in google and copied the link address. I works in my localhost